# Preview saved image in database using PHP and jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have uploaded and stored multiple images at a time in a MySQL database using jQuery and PHP. This time I am storing image name in database and uploads file in a folder at server.
Now, I want to retrieve image name from database and preview this image and also want to provide actions of delete and add images.

Can anyone help me out on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my steps:

1. Create a php file
2. Connect to mysql database
3. Select the table where the images was saved.
4. Loop the query.
5. Add delete query.

Hope this helps.